# How to segregate files based on recursive grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have a directory, sub-directories each containing some text files.

```
 main-dir
  |
  sub-dir1
         | file1 "foo"
  |
  sub-dir2
         | file2 "bar"
  |
  sub-dir3
         | file3 "foo"
```

These files file1, file2 contain same text. I want to segregate these sub-directories based on content of files. I would like to group sub-dir1 and sub-dir3 as files in these sub-dirs have same content. In this example, move sub-dir1 and sub-dir3 to another directory.

using grep in recursive mode lists out all subdirectories matching file content. How can I make use that of output.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "segregate"? Do you want to move them to other directories?

Comment: It is not yet clear (to me) what you are asking to do.  You appear to be wanting to move files around, based on whether the files contain some particular pattern that can be found by `grep`.  The files that do match should be moved to some as yet unidentified location; the files that do not match might be left where they are, or moved to another as yet unidentified location.  You need to edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write this script which solves my question.

```
PWD=`$pwd`
FILES=$PWD/*

for f in $FILES
do
    str=$(cat $f/file1)
    if [ "$str" == "foo" ];
    then
         cp -rf $f $HOME_PATH/newdir/
    fi

done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution could be simplified to this:

```
for dir in *; do
  if grep "foo" "$dir/file1" >/dev/null; then
    cp -rf "$dir" "$HOME_PATH/newdir/"
  fi
done
```

but will work only when all directories actually contain a file `file1`.

Something like this:

```
grep -rl "foo" * | sed -r 's|(.*)/.*|\1|' | sort -u | while read dir; do
  cp -rf "$dir" "$HOME_PATH/newdir/"
done
```

or like this:

```
grep -rl "foo" * | while read f; do
  dirname "$f"
done | sort -u | while read dir; do
  cp -rf "$dir" "$HOME_PATH/newdir/"
done
```

or like this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l "foo" {} \; | xargs -I {} dirname {} | sort -u |
  while read dir; do
    cp -rf "$dir" "$HOME_PATH/newdir/"
  done
```

might be better.